# Fetch the result of the row -1

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe (the actual df is bigger but just using this for understanding purposes)

```
product test_result, benchmark
1, 1.1, 1
1, 2.1, 3
1, 2.1, 2
```

A product passed a test when the `test_result > benchmark`. What I would like to do now is add one column that states whether 
the product passed the last test. So `df$result_last_test` for row 2 should be `PASSED` and for row 3 `FAILED`.

So the expected output should be

```
product test_result, benchmark, test_result_previous
1, 1.1, 1, NA
1, 2.1, 3, PASSED
1, 2.1, 2 FAILED
```

I am looking for a way now to compare to the previous product. My first idea would be to create a loop and fetch the semi-last item in the list? Any feedback on my approach / problem?

Comment: Could you be more precise on what do you want to do? An example of expected output would be also helpful.

Comment: So for the first row, it is "FAILED"?

Comment: if the test is test_result > benchmark, than 2.1 coes not pass it comparing to 3...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple and you do not need any loops in here:

```
n <- length(test_result)
test <- c(NA, test_result[1:(n-1)] > test_result)
```

or with simpler code (check if difference between time `t` and `t-1` is greater than 0):

```
test <- c(NA, diff(test_result) > 0)
```

next, name the output with

```
ifelse(test, "PASSED", "FAILED")
```